# Failed to convert string to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm working on a login page that takes the password from a text field and then on button click the value is compared to the database but when I try to use the SqlDataReader I then get the error the conversion from string to byte[] failed.

```cs
byte[] pswBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(psw);
var byte64 = Convert.ToBase64String(pswBytes);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value 
        = email;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@psw", SqlDbType.VarBinary, byte64.Length).Value = byte64;

    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {}
}
```

the password in the database is a byte(64) as well.

Error is:

InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'.
System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)

InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[].
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(object value, MetaType destinationType, out bool coercedToDataFeed, out bool typeChanged, bool allowStreaming)

Comment: If there's an error then there's an error message giving more information. Add that to your question.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I included the error

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String` returns a string. Did you mean to use `pswBytes` instead of `byte64`?

Comment: @Chris Are you referring to cmd.Parameters.Add("@psw", SqlDbType.VarBinary, byte64.Length).Value = byte64;

Comment: Yes. [VarBinary maps to byte array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#specifying-parameter-data-types)

Comment: @Chris What you pointed out was the correct response.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but note that storing passwords this way is considered unsafe. It’s better to hash the password so the original password can no longer be discovered. See: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html and https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DotNet_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why convert `pswBytes` to a `string`? When the data type is binary, the input data type of the program must be an array of bytes.

```
byte[] pswBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(psw);
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = email;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@psw", SqlDbType.VarBinary, pswBytes.Length).Value = pswBytes;

   con.Open();

   using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {}
}
```